# NumPy: TypeError: reshape() got an unexpected keyword argument 'order'

Tags: python, numpy, fipy

I get the following error while reshaping a numpy ndarray

```
DeprecationWarning: :func:`reshape` is deprecated, use :func:`numerix.reshape()<numpy.reshape>` instead!
return reshape(newshape, order=order)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./render2.py", line 374, in <module>
,u=np.reshape(voltage.grad[0], (ny, nx))
File "/home/jana/Builds/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 172,  in reshape
return reshape(newshape, order=order)
File "/home/jana/Builds/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fipy/tools/decorators.py", line 151, in newfunc
return func(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: reshape() got an unexpected keyword argument 'order'
```

Below is the part of the code that gives this error. Note: plot.py is a user defined module.

```
plot.streamlinePlot(x = x
                   ,y = y
                   ,u=np.reshape(voltage.grad[0], (ny, nx))
                   ,v=np.reshape(voltage.grad[1], (ny, nx))
                   ,filename='Analysis/electricFieldStreamPlot_%s.png'
                   ,show=False
                   ,clear=True)
```

The output of

```
print "Voltage shape =", voltage.shape
print "Voltage.grad[0] shape =", voltage.grad[0].shape
print "ny times nx =", ny*nx
```

is

```
Voltage shape = (269700,)
Voltage.grad[0] shape = (269700,)
ny times nx = 269700
```

I am running FiPy 3.0 and NumPy 1.7.2.
Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: please post the code you were running (enough to reproduce the error) and the versions of numpy and fipy

Comment: It seems it may be a bug in fipy. Can you run `np.reshape(voltage.grad[0], (ny, nx)` without importing fipy first?

Answer (score 1):

You should get the desired result by calling

```
from fipy import numerix as nx
nx.reshape(voltage.grad[0], (ny, nx))
```

FiPy overrides a number of NumPy routines for working with its own data structures in a self-consistent way. You should always use fipy.numerix instead of numpy when working with FiPy objects.

If you aren't aware, FiPY now includes a [MatplotlibStreamViewer](http://matforge.org/fipy/browser/fipy/fipy/viewers/matplotlibViewer/matplotlibStreamViewer.py) that may either serve your needs or at least show you the data manipulations you'll need to perform for your own display.

There's definitely something wrong in the interaction between numpy.reshape(), fipy.numerix.reshape(), and fipy.CellVariable.reshape(). I've filed [a ticket](http://matforge.org/fipy/ticket/664) to look into this. Thanks for raising the question.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. However, I get the error:`u=nx.reshape(voltage.grad[0], (ny, nx))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'reshape'`

Comment: Try `u=nx.reshape(voltage.grad[...,0], (ny, nx))`. The dimension needs to be the last index, not the first index.